# Craft 2.5 option to embed image with transform missing

Tags: image, image-transforms, richtext

I know Craft 2.5 uses Redactor II so I assume this problem relates to this, but it would be good to get this confirmed.

Setting aside the fact you need to update the configs, I have noticed the ability to embed an image (in a Rich Text field) with a transform is no longer an option.

In Craft 2.4 there was another button adjacent to the Select button to upload an image with a pre-defined transform. This is missing.

I have also noticed that the image select modal does not close once an image is selected either by double-clicking it or pressing the select button.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issues?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I was about to post this question. I'm on OS X El Capitan and latest Safari.

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this is a bug which has been fixed. Closing as a "bug report".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in the next (post [2.5.2750](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750)) release.